# partial fetch IMAP causes latency? (mail.imap.partialfetch)

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

We have written an email listener that listens to Lotusnotes mail box. We are seeing an issue where "From" address is incorrectly read once the email is processed. It takes the "From" address from a different email in the inbox. 
Java mailapi FAQs suggest to disable "mail.imap.partialfetch" to false when there is loss in data. I want to understand if disabling this will cause any performance impact? Our customer is running on production and wants to test this setting there.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#imapserverbug

Comment: Do you get correct from address values when disabling mail.imap.partialfetch? I think this parameter has effect when handling the content.

Comment: Right, partialfetch won't effect the header information for the message.  If you're getting the wrong header information, there's a bug in your program or there's a bug in the IMAP server.  The link you include above might work around the bug in the server, but that's unrelated to partialfetch.